# How to skip (omit) a specific port in nmap

Tags: nmap

With nmap, I want to skip the scan on port 80.  I'm sure this is in the man somewhere, but I haven't found it so far.  My command is simple:

```
nmap 24.0.0.1\24
```

So this will scan ports in the 24.0.0.x range; I just need to avoid port 80 (for stealth reasons).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `--exclude-ports` option. Not sure why this wasn't mentioned earlier. Maybe it's new. I am using Nmap 7.01. So in your case you could simply do:

```
$ nmap 24.0.0.1\24 --exclude-ports 80
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use comma as a separator to separate two different ranges of port. For ex. in your case you can give the following

`$ nmap 24.0.0.0/24 -p 1-79,81-65535`

Hence this way we omitted port scanning on port 80.

Comment: Nmap scans 1000 ports by default. This changes it to scan 65534 ports. To get the same ports as default without 80, try this: `nmap 24.0.0.0/24 -p -79,81- --top-ports 999`